# Traffic overlay for Poland

Tags: google-maps

There is a traffic overlay service for Poland available on main google
map website. Unfortunately i can not see that data on my own website
created by API.

There is no traffic data for Poland on an example site as well
http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/trafficOverlay.html

(the same situation on api v2 and v3)

Why it is like that? When (and if) it will be available?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when it will be available, I don't think they really tend to pre-announce those things.

However, there is a [spreadsheet of coverage data](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html) which lists everywhere that has traffic data. Unfortunately, Polands's not on it for now.

Comment: Thanks! It is odd as they acquireing that data anyway:) [Traffic overlay for Warsaw](http://mapy.google.pl/?ll=52.222121,21.051865&spn=0.163418,0.528374&t=h&z=12&layer=t)